# PHP CLI writing and reading multiple raw tcp API's in parallel like curl_multi_init for https API's

Tags: php, curl, tcp, client

My situation:

I have multiple servers running a raw TCP API that requires me to send a string to get information from them. I need to get a response within a timeout of 5 seconds. All APIs should be contacted at the same time and from there on they got 5 seconds to respond. (So the maximum execution time is 5 seconds for all servers at once)

I already managed to do so for HTTP/S APIs with PHP cURL:

```
// array of curl handles
$multiCurl = array();
// data to be returned
$result = array();
// multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($row_apis as $api) {
    $id = $api[0];
    $ip = $api[1];
    $port = $api[2];
  // URL from which data will be fetched
  $fetchURL = "$ip:$port/api/status";
  $multiCurl[$id] = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$id], CURLOPT_URL,$fetchURL);
  //curl_setopt($multiCurl[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$id], CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$id], CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"GET");
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multiCurl[$id]);
}
$index=null;
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
} while($index > 0);
// get content and remove handles
foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) {
  $result[$k] = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($ch), true);
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}
// close
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

This sample fetches all APIs at once and waits 5 seconds for a respose. It will never take longer than 5 seconds.

Is there a way to do the same thing with raw TCP APIs in PHP?
I already tried to use sockets and was able to get the information but every API is fetched after another, so the script takes way to long for multiple servers.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I've tried to implement your suggestions and my code now looks like this:

```
$apis = array();
$apis[0] = array(1, "123.123.123.123", 1880);

$method = "summary";
$sockets = array();

//Create socket array
foreach($apis as $api){
    $id = $api[0];
    $ip = $api[1];
    $port = $api[2];

    $sockets[$id] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_nonblock($sockets[$id]);
    @socket_connect($sockets[$id], $ip, $port);
    //socket_write($sockets[$id], $method);
}

//Write to every socket
/*
foreach($sockets as $socket){
    socket_write($socket, $method);
    //fwrite($socket, "$method");
}
*/

//Read all sockets for 5 seconds
$write  = NULL;
$except = NULL;
$responses = socket_select($sockets, $write, $except, 5);

//Check result
if($responses === false){
    echo "Did not work";
}
elseif($responses > 0){
    echo "At least one has responded";
}

//Access the data
//???
```

But I'm getting a 0 as the result of socket_select...
When do I need to write the method to the socket?
And if I will get something back, how do I access the data that was in the response?

Answer (score 0):

absolutely. set `SO_SNDBUF` to the appropriate size, so you can send all the requests instantly/non-blockingly, then send all the reqeusts, then start waiting for/reading the responses.

the easy way to do the reading is to call `socket_set_block` on the sockets, and read all responses 1 by 1, but this doesn't give a hard guarantee of a 5 second timeout (but then again, neither does your example curl_multi code), if you need a 5 second timeout, use `socket_set_nonblock` & `socket_select` instead.